# Typescript + VS Code: Cannot find module "myimage.png"

Tags: reactjs, image, typescript, webpack, import

I want to import an image from an assets directory within my project. **It works fine**, however, VS Code complains saying that:

`Cannot find module '../../../shared/assets/images/logo.png'.ts(2307)`

These are my type definitions:

```
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.json';
declare module '*.svg';
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the file containing the type definitions isn't loaded.

## Fix

- Ensure the file is included (e.g. matches the `include` in tsconfig.json)
- Restart vscode